# Creating a Paged UIScrollView that trigger a Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am looking for a way to create a paging UIScrollView that allows me to trigger a segue based on which page a user presses.

The part of the app that this is related to is a set of blog posts that are contained in a UITableView, where the first row in the tableview is the scrollview. The scrollview has 5 different pages that a user can flick through horizontally of the latest 5 blog posts with images. I have spent a while trying to learn how to do paged scrollviews but am now stuck on how I would get each to segue to their specific blog post as I do in the TableView below it.

Does anyone have any recommendations of how I would achieve this or potentially somewhere they know that has published a good method? Everything I can think of (like overlaying a UIButton on each page of the ScrollView) doesn't sound like a very good way of getting it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add the segue to the page object (a WebView or whatever you decided worked best for visualizing the page) itself, not to the UIScrollView or UIPageControl.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly I should be able to trigger a segue from a user tapping one of the (for example) UIView's that I have as a page in my UIScrollView?

Comment: @tizaks Yes you can link a segue to an action on the UIView, you will have a reference to the UIView in which you should know to which page you should go